# Реализация записи в массив,с сохранением, что использовать?

Tags: android, массивы

Есть 2 массива 2 едит текста 2 спинера  и 4 кнопки,как сделать так чтобы можно было кнопками добавлять введенное слово в массив,и сохранять его там, даже после закрытия приложения? сразу говорю списки де длинные всего по 10-15 значений, но значение уникальные будут, поэтому нужна возможность редактирования

```
   import android.os.Build;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.AdapterView;
     import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Activity_setting extends AppCompatActivity {

Button but_del,but_add,but_text_del,but_text_add;//добавляем кнопки

EditText editText,editText2;//добавляем текстовое поле

Spinner spinner_resh,spinner_text;//добавляем списки

public String[] data_resh = {"жел", "сам", "недозвон", "отказ", "по", "поаб", "вм"};


public String[] data_text = {"нет дома", "замена роутера", "ыволраолывр", "отказ", "по", "поаб", "вм"};


public String[] getData_resh() {
    return data_resh;
}

public String[] getData_text() {
    return data_text;
}

String sResh ="сам";
String sText ="абонента нет дома";

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    but_text_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_text_add);
    but_text_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    but_text_del = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_text_del);
    but_text_del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    but_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_add);
    but_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    but_del = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_del);
    but_del.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_resh = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data_resh);
    adapter_resh.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_resh = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.resh_list);
    spinner_resh.setAdapter(adapter_resh);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_text = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data_text);
    adapter_text.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_text = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.text_list);
    spinner_text.setAdapter(adapter_text);

    // заголовок в этой теме нет
    spinner_resh.setPrompt("Title");
    spinner_text.setPrompt("Title_2");

    // выделяем элемент который будет стоять первый
    spinner_resh.setSelection(3);
    spinner_text.setSelection(3);


    // устанавливаем обработчик нажатия
    spinner_resh.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // показываем позиция нажатого элемента(в переменную реш заносится значение выбранного элемента)
            sResh = spinner_resh.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "#" + resh, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }


    });
    spinner_text.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // показываем позиция нажатого элемента(в переменную реш заносится значение выбранного элемента)
            sText = spinner_text.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "#" + resh, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }


    });







}
```

}

Comment: sqlite подойдет для задачи.

Comment: для этого нужен сервер?хотелосьб бы без сети

Comment: SQLite не нужно сервер

Comment: sharedPreferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Вам нужно обеспечить долговременное сохранение данных пользователя то лучше реализовать их хранение в БД SQLite. При этом в Вашем коде надо будет реализовать создание БД и взаимодействие с ней. А уже на устройствах пользователя Андроид позаботится чтобы все отработало корректно т.к. SQLite входит в в состав библиотек ОС Андроид.